# How do I put variable values into a text string in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, text, variables

I'm trying to write a simple function that takes two inputs, `x` and `y`, and passes these to three other simple functions that add, multiply, and divide them. The main function should then display the results as a string containing `x`, `y`, and the totals.

I think there's something I'm not understanding about output arguments. Anyway, here's my (pitiful) code:

```
function a=addxy(x,y)
a=x+y;

function b=mxy(x,y)
b=x*y;

function c=dxy(x,y)
c=x/y;
```

The main function is:

```
function [d e f]=answer(x,y)
d=addxy(x,y);
e=mxy(x,y);
f=dxy(x,y);
z=[d e f]
```

How do I get the values for `x`, `y`, `d`, `e`, and `f` into a string? I tried different matrices and stuff like:

```
['the sum of' x 'and' y 'is' d]
```

but none of the variables are showing up.

Two additional issues:

- Why is the function returning "ans 3" even though I didn't ask for the length of `z`?
- If anyone could recommend a good book for beginners to MATLAB scripting I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: use sprintf: str='DEF'; var=sprint('abc%sghi',str);  => abcDEFghi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204579/getting-variable-values-into-a-text-string-matlab/2204594#2204594) and [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204579/getting-variable-values-into-a-text-string-matlab/2204631#2204631) illustrate, you have to convert numeric values to formatted strings first in order to display them or concatenate them with other character strings. You can do this using the functions [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html), [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html), [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html), and [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html).

---

With respect to getting `ans = 3` as an output, it is probably because you are not assigning the output from `answer` to a variable. If you want to get all of the output values, you will have to call `answer` in the following way:

```
[out1,out2,out3] = answer(1,2);
```

This will place the value `d` in `out1`, the value `e` in `out2`, and the value `f` in `out3`. When you do the following:

```
answer(1,2)
```

MATLAB will automatically assign the first output `d` (which has the value 3 in this case) to the default workspace variable [`ans`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ans.html).

---

With respect to suggesting a good resource for learning MATLAB, you shouldn't underestimate the value of the MATLAB documentation. I've learned most of what I know on my own using it. You can access it [online](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html), or within your copy of MATLAB using the functions [DOC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/doc.html), [HELP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/help.html), or [HELPWIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/helpwin.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. Just one more quick question - if I create an output variable in one function - for example:

function a=simple(x);
a=x^2;

how can i access the value of 'a' from other functions? For example:

function b=simple2(x);
b=a*x; %calling on a from 'simple'

Comment: @jefflovejapan: In such a case, your second function would be `function b = simple2(x) b = simple(x)*x;`. In other words, you would call `simple` within `simple2` and its output will be used in the equation for `b`.

Answer (score 16):

Here's how you convert numbers to strings, and join strings to other things (it's weird):

```
>> ['the number is ' num2str(15) '.']
ans =
the number is 15.
```

Comment: That was helpful, but it's still not working the way I want it to. When I run the function on (1,2) I get ans=3 , which means that the other two functions, mxy and dxy, aren't seeing the values of x and y. Also, the values for all of the output arguments are empty.

I think there's something really simple that I'm not doing here with the variables, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 8):

You can use fprintf/sprintf with familiar C syntax. Maybe something like:

```
fprintf('x = %d, y = %d \n x+y=%d \n x*y=%d \n x/y=%f\n', x,y,d,e,f)
```

---

reading your comment, this is how you use your functions from the main program:

```
x = 2;
y = 2;
[d e f] = answer(x,y);
fprintf('%d + %d = %d\n', x,y,d)
fprintf('%d * %d = %d\n', x,y,e)
fprintf('%d / %d = %f\n', x,y,f)
```

Also for the *answer()* function, you can assign the output values to a vector instead of three distinct variables:

```
function result=answer(x,y)
result(1)=addxy(x,y);
result(2)=mxy(x,y);
result(3)=dxy(x,y);
```

and call it simply as:

```
out = answer(x,y);
```

Comment: thanks, this is definitely simpler, but the exercise specifically asks you to build functions and to have them pass variables back and forth.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot. It's cool that you don't have to specify the size of 'result' beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

I just realized why I was having so much trouble - in MATLAB you can't store strings of different lengths as an array using square brackets. Using square brackets concatenates strings of varying lengths into a single *character* array.

```
    >> a=['matlab','is','fun']

a =

matlabisfun

>> size(a)

ans =

     1    11
```

In a character array, each character in a string counts as one element, which explains why the size of a is 1X11.

To store strings of varying lengths as elements of an array, you need to use curly braces to save as a cell array. In cell arrays, each string is treated as a separate element, regardless of length.

```
>> a={'matlab','is','fun'}

a = 

    'matlab'    'is'    'fun'

>> size(a)

ans =

     1     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something along what you wanted, but wanted to put it back into a variable.

So this is what I did

`variable = ['hello this is x' x ', this is now y' y ', finally this is d:' d]`

basically

`variable = [str1 str2 str3 str4 str5 str6]`