# Concatenation: number to string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, casting, concatenation

I have forgotten this: I need to concatenate numbers like `'1'+'2'->'12'`. I am trying to find a concatenate command `String(var1)+String(var2)`. What is the concatenation command for Matlab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I put variable values into a text string in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204579/how-do-i-put-variable-values-into-a-text-string-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things: convert the numbers to strings, then concatenate.  The solution is:

```
newString = [ num2str(var1) num2str(var2) ]
```

The result will be a string.

Comment: why [...] and not strcat? Any benefit? Otherwise same as mine.

Comment: @hhh Sorry, answered in a comment on your answer ;)

Comment: I suppose you *could* argue a speed benefit for my answer, but I think you'd be unlikely to ever be in a situation where it made a difference...

Answer (score 2):

This is my alternative, no idea whether any better to jazzbassrob's solution.

```
strcat(num2str(1),num2str(324))
```

Comment: I think in this instance they're basically equivalent.  `strcat` is able to handle things like cell arrays of strings, which aren't being used here.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter (and faster) alternative to `num2str` and catenation may be [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html). For example:

```
sprintf('%d%d', var1, var2)
```